# Update first header column based on checkbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have table format mentioned in JSP.If someone clicks a checkbox on page I want to update first column of table header.

e.g. If checkbox is not checked:
Table header : 
A B C

If checkbox is checked: 
Table header : 
D B C

As far I am just able to understand change has to managed client side only. So I don't think JSP can help here.I have to go with JQuery in this case. Please help me correct my understanding I am new to web development. Till now I was trying to achieve this with JSP and its not working:

```
 <% boolean flag=false; %>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 if (document.getElementById("checkBoxName").checked) {
     <% flag=true %>
 }
 </script>
 <% if(flag==true) { %>
   <th>A</th>
 <% }
 else { %>
   <th>D</th>
 <% } %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) method to handle change event and [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to change content inside it

```js
$('#checkBoxName').change(function() {
  var checked = this.checked
  $('th').html(function() {
    return checked ? 'ABC' : 'DEF';
  });
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkBoxName" />
<table>
  <th></th>
</table>
```